# Autowiring Feign interface located in JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, feign

I have a `AttachmentApi` service class that uses a `feign interface` both located inside a `JAR` file that i'm using as dependency in a `client microservice`.
The `controller` of that client microservice uses the `AttachmentApi` service to get data from db.
When I access some endpoint of that controller, the AttachmentApi service is 
 successfully autowired but the feign interface isn't, and it gives me the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at ma.co.omnidata.framework.services.attachment.api.AttachmentApi.upload(AttachmentApi.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
at ma.co.omnidata.attachment.user.service.impl.AttachmentsUserService.uploadFile(AttachmentsUserService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
at ma.co.omnidata.attachment.user.controllers.AttachmentUserController.uploadFile(AttachmentUserController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

The null is due to the feign interface that does not get autowired !

Knowing that I use the following annotations in my springboot class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages= {"my.packages.including.the.feign.interface.package"})
```

Any advice would be appreciated
thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Feign interface (Located in the JAR dependency)

```
@FeignClient(name="attachment-service", fallback=AttachmentHystrixFallback.class)
public interface AttachmentFeignClient {

@RequestMapping("attachment/{id}")
byte[] getAttachment(@PathVariable(name="id") String id);

@RequestMapping("attachments")
List<AttachmentDto> getAttachments(@RequestParam(name="attachableId") Long attachableId, 
        @RequestParam(name="className") String className, @RequestParam(name="appName") String appName);

@RequestMapping("upload")
void upload(MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(name="attachableId") Long attachableId, 
        @RequestParam(name="className") String className, @RequestParam(name="appName") String appName);

@RequestMapping("test")
String test();
```

}

The AttachmentApi (Located in the JAR dependency too)

```
@Service
public class AttachmentApi implements IAttachmentApi {

@Autowired
AttachmentFeignClient client;

@Override
public byte[] getAttachment(String id) {
    return client.getAttachment(id);
}

@Override
public void upload(IAttachable entity, MultipartFile file) {
    client.upload(file, entity.getAttachableId(), entity.getClassName(), entity.getAppName());
}

@Override
public List<AttachmentDto> getAttachments(IAttachable entity) {
    return client.getAttachments(entity.getAttachableId(), entity.getClassName(), entity.getAppName());
}


public String test() {
    return client.test();
}
```

}

NB : My client microservice cannot autowire any of the beans (neither the Feign interface nor the AttachmentApi class) located in the JAR dependency !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@EnableFeignClients(clients = {AttachmentFeignClient.class})
```